# Difference between html link parser and http url rewriting modifier

Tags: jmeter

What are the differences between **html link parser** and **http url rewriting modifier**.
explain with scenarios they are used in jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

What is the context? StackOverflow is not a suitable place for looking for the answers for interview questions or doing a homework. In order to get an answer you need to describe the problem, what have you tried so far and what do you want to achieve.

- HTML Link Parser has 2 main use cases:

  1. Choose random values or values from a given range when there is a choice, see [Poll Example](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#poll_example) for details
  2. Act as a website crawler (for broken links checking or simulating users browsing around the site), see [How to Spider a Site with JMeter - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-spider-site-jmeter-tutorial) for example usage.
- HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier is being used when a dynamic parameter is being appended to the URL representing a user session or other mandatory parameter. See [Correlation with HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](https://jmeterworld.wordpress.com/2009/01/02/http-url-re-writing-modifier/) article for more information.